# path visibility from source to destination in googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, youtube

Path visibility from Source to Destination in Google Maps. The Source and Destination places must be retrieved from the backend and it should shown in the google map. the detailed description for my requirement is given in image. i have searched in youtube but it is showing that the source is constant and the destination varies by the movement of marker.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code is use to redirect to the google map and give you a path between source and destination :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + doubleLatStart + "," + doubleLonStart + "&daddr=" + doubleLatEnd + "," + doubleLonEnd + "&mode=driving"));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

here, **doubleLatStart** is latitude of your source location and **doubleLonStart** is longitude of your source location.
**doubleLatEnd** is latitude of destination location and doubleLonEnd is longitude of destination location.

Let me know if you have any further query.

Comment: Thankyou so much for giving this idea. I will apply and let u know the output.

Comment: Sure,let me know if you any query.

Comment: doubleLatStart ,doubleLonStart,doubleLatEnd,doubleLonEnd thes terms are getting error. where i have intialise these terms.

Comment: plz clarify my question

Comment: in place of this you need to put values of latitude and longitude whichever you are getting from database

Comment: I have given the doubleLatStart ,doubleLonStart,doubleLatEnd,doubleLonEnd values to the java code above the "button.on click listener".

Comment: As doubleLatStart = 12.9716 ,doubleLonStart = 77.5946 ,doubleLatEnd = 28.7041 ,doubleLonEnd = 77.1025 i.e., source=bangalore and destination = new delhi.

Comment: i was given this values as example, because currently i am dealing with frontend design. so, i have given these fake values for testing the output is properly coming or not.

Comment: But now i am getting the path for source(mylocation) to destination(Newdelhi).  But i want the source location is from Bangalore. but the output is coming for Mylocation(source) to NewDelhi(Destination).